# jQuery editGridRow window won't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is code:

```
 $("#addpesel").click(function(){
            var properties = {
                height: 280,
                reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
            }
            jQuery("#blacklist").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",properties);
        });
```

after click "save" window won't close. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example which does `"Edit"` - > `"Save"` -> `"Cancel"` functionality respectively.

**HTML**

```
...
<table id="rowed1"></table>
<div id="prowed1"></div>
<br />
<input type="BUTTON" id="ed1" value="Edit row 13" />
<input type="BUTTON" id="sved1" disabled='true' value="Save row 13" />
<input type="BUTTON" id="cned1" disabled='true' value="Cancel Save" />

<script src="rowedex1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery("#ed1").click( function() {
    jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('editRow',"13");
    this.disabled = 'true';
    jQuery("#sved1,#cned1").attr("disabled",false);
});
jQuery("#sved1").click( function() {
    jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('saveRow',"13");
    jQuery("#sved1,#cned1").attr("disabled",true);
    jQuery("#ed1").attr("disabled",false);
});
jQuery("#cned1").click( function() {
    jQuery("#rowed1").jqGrid('restoreRow',"13");
    jQuery("#sved1,#cned1").attr("disabled",true);
    jQuery("#ed1").attr("disabled",false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps: jQuery('#blacklist).jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma at the end of your properties var and I might set the var like
var = '{ blah blah balh }';  Looks like you are one set of "});" short as well.

But I would not use the var at all.  Here is a working function I have pulled out of one of my grids.  Instead of addpesel, my button id is addentity and my grid id is entities.

```
        $("#addentity").click(function(){ var rowadder = jQuery("#entities").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{ height:100, reloadAfterSubmit:true, closeAfterAdd: true   }); });
```